# Launch bar shortcuts vanish after some time

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, icons

I have Ubuntu 21.04 (upgraded from previous release) and noticed this strange behavior...

Right after reboot, I can see my shortcut icons in the launch bar:

[image]

But then after a few minutes, only the 9 dots icon is left...

[image]

I also noticed there's no way to show the launch bar by moving mouse to bottom (I have it setup at bottom) no matter what, even though auto-hide is set to True

[image]

I assume the issue is related...this is really annoying and I'm forced to use Cairo Dock in the meantime...any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: 1) This could be "upgrade pain": a fresh install is always better 2) 21.04 is end of life very soon, so not much worth investigating further: upgrade to 21.10. In the mean time, temporarily create a new account, see if the problem persists there: allows you to determine whether it is an issue in your user configuration or a system wide issue.

Comment: yeah I wanted to avoid upgrading again because when I do that I have problems with python and pyenv, but I guess it will happen anyway...will give it a try...otherwise fresh install but I really wanted to avoid having to restore data and specific configuration files for the many stuff I have installed...should've stayed with my good old LTS :D

Comment: You can try upgrading first. Against my own opinion, I also have been upgrading over the last few editions, last time without any issue at all.

Comment: So I did upgrade @vanadium and now is even worse :D all my previous shortcuts are gone...and there seems to be no easy way to add them back...so I guess I'll keep using Cairo

Comment: You forgot plan B, the best approach: a fresh install. Upgrading can keep maintaining corrupt configuration.

Comment: lol, yes I'll have go that way at the end...still, it feels unfortunate...forces me to reinstall so much stuff...